# Selecting $3$ at a time, what is the probability of selecting at least $2$ girls out of a group of $10$ girls and $5$ boys?

Tags: probability

There are $15$ students in math class. Five of them are boys. Three students are selected to participate in an exam. Find the probability of selecting  at least $2$ girls.

Comment: Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck. Also have a look at [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Answer (score 2):

The total number of the possible choises is $\binom{3}{15}$, so I think that your solution should be $$ P=1-\frac{\binom{3}{5}+10\binom{2}{5}}{\binom{3}{15}}$$ (the first term in the numerator is the number of possible choises of three boys, while the second is the possible number of 2 boys and one girl).

Comment: There are $10$ girls and $5$ boys.  You seem to have reversed the numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it with the right numbers!